# MS SQL Join Two Tables with 'IN' Faces Problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables for my system.

Table 1: Book

[image]

Table 2: BookStatus

[image]

Now I want to find out the **latest status** of books that had been lent **from 2018/11/05 to 201/11/10** and **how many times they have been lent** during this period.

The result I expect is like:
[image]

My SQL script is:

```
SELECT BK.*, 
       BS.status, BS.statusDateTime, 
       (SELECT count(*) FROM BookStatus WHERE status='lent' AND bookId=BK.bookId AND statusDateTime>='2018/11/05 00:00:00' AND statusDatetime<='2018/11/10 23:59:59' ) CountLent 
FROM  Book BK LEFT JOIN BookStatus BS ON BK.bookId = BS.bookId 
WHERE BS.statusId = (SELECT max(statusId) FROM BookStatus WHERE bookId= BK.bookId)
AND BK.bookId IN (SELECT bookId FROM BookStatus WHERE status='lent' AND statusDateTime>='2018/11/05 00:00:00' AND statusDatetime<='2018/11/10 23:59:59')
```

After I execute the sql query, it just keeps running and doesn't stop. 
Is there any problem with my SQL query script?
How to revise my SQL script to have the result I expect?

Comment: Post tables and results as text, not as images. And learn to use a proper JOIN

Comment: I tried FROM Book BK LEFT JOIN BookStatus BS ON BK.bookId=BS.bookId,  but it stil keeps running and doesn't stop.

Comment: That is not my point, using JOIN is the preferred and best way to combine (join) two tables.

Comment: Joakim Danielson Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out all the books that were lent during the period and the count using a sub query. Use `CROSS APPLY` to fetch the latest status:

```
WITH activity AS (
    SELECT bookId, COUNT(*) AS CountLent
    FROM BookStatus
    WHERE statusDateTime >= '2018-11-05' AND statusDateTime < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2018-11-10')
    AND status = 'lent'
    GROUP BY bookId
)
SELECT Book.*, activity.CountLent, lastStatus.*
FROM Book
INNER JOIN activity ON Book.bookId = activity.bookId
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 status, statusDateTime FROM BookStatus WHERE bookId = Book.bookId ORDER BY statusDateTime DESC) AS lastStatus
```

Comment: Your code looks much simple and understandable with `CROSS APPLY` to solve my problem . Thanks a lot and cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

Please try your query like below-

```
   select b.bookid ,b.bookName , b.Author 
,bs.status ,max(bs.statusDatetime), count(bs.status) Countlent
    from Book b 
    join BookStatus bs on b.bookid= bs.bookid
    where bs.statusDateTime >='2018/11/05 00:00:00' AND bs.statusDatetime<='2018/11/10 23:59:59'
    and bs.status = 'lent'
    group by b.bookid ,b.bookName , b.Author ,bs.status
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: What if the latest status was "available" inside that time period?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
  select b.bookid ,b.bookName , b.Author ,bs.status ,
    max(bs.statusDatetime) as statusDatetime, count(bs.status) Countlent
    from Book b 
    join BookStatus bs on b.bookid= bs.bookid
    where bs.statusDateTime >='2018/11/05 00:00:00' AND bs.statusDatetime<='2018/11/10 23:59:59' and bs.status = 'lent'
    group by b.bookid ,b.bookName , b.Author ,bs.status
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried run your code, and it was ok, but result was not true! You can try this:

```
  SELECT    bd.bookID, bk.bookName, bk.author, 
            statusID, status, statusDateTime ,bc.countLent  
  FROM   ( SELECT    bookID, statusDate = MAX(statusDateTime)
              FROM      bookStatus
              GROUP BY  bookID
         ) AS bd
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  bookID, COUNT(*) AS countLent
                    FROM    bookStatus
                    WHERE   [status] = 'lent'
                    GROUP BY bookID
                  ) AS bc ON bc.bookID = bd.bookID
        LEFT JOIN dbo.bookStatus ON bookStatus.bookID = bc.bookID
                                    AND bd.statusDate = dbo.bookStatus.statusDateTime
        LEFT JOIN Book AS bk ON bk.bookID = bookStatus.bookID
```

The result is good but I know my code is not the best way :D Hope this's help